# Not getting Json results with latest Jackson using jersey 2.22.1

Tags: json, jersey, jackson, jersey-2.0, objectmapper

I am using jersey v2.21 and I am trying to set my `ObjectMapper` with couple of configurations:

1. Don't return a property if its value is `null`
2. Return the properties of object ordered alphabetically
3. Return dates in a format like this: `2015-06-22T17:57:05.000-07:00`

This how my ObjectMapper looks like:
**Edited:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat;

/**
 * Created by Shiran Maor on 1/13/16.
 */
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper defaultMapper;

    public ObjectMapperResolver() {
        this.defaultMapper = createDefaultMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        return this.defaultMapper;
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
        ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
        result = result.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        result = result.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);
        result = result.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);

        result.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        result.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());

        return result;

    }

}
```

**Edit:**
These are my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.21</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
      <version>2.21</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Edit:**
This is the tree dependencies:

```
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:6.8.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
[INFO] |  \- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.27:test
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:provided
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.22.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.22.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.1:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.21:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.21:runtime
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.5.4:runtime
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.21:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b31:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b31:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b31:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b31:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b31:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.0:runtime
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.7.0:runtime
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider:jar:2.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.7.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:test
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.6.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:jar:2.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:runtime
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.11:runtime
[INFO] \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:runtime
```

**Edit:**
This is my web.xml part:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>api-service-endpoints</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
                     com.mypack
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

However, I am getting `null` values, not alphabetic, and with dates represented in milliseconds.

**Update:**
After updating the dependencies, I am getting this exception:

```
        <pre>org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase.&lt;init&gt;(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperConfig;)V
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.anaplan.api.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:63)
</pre>
```

**Update1:**
I was reading about depedencies issues that jersey have and when I removed:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.21</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am getting  the result as expected, BUT, only in xml, not in json.
any ideas?

Comment: Did you set (not in the current example) `Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`? Did it work?

Comment: @engineer , just did and it didn't work. Looks like it is being ignored/overridden from other place?

Comment: Put a print statement in the `getContext`. Is it being called?

Comment: @peeskillet no, getContext is not being called (even after making a call)

Comment: @peeskillet: When I changed from org.codehaus.jackson to com.fasterxml.jackson dependencies, I managed to stop on getContext but than I am getting the error I mentioned later:
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()
I guess something is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ObjectMapper` works perfectly (with some minor modifications) as long as you're using it correctly (e.g., registering jackson feature and registering your provider in the jax-rs application).

If you substitute `MyObjectMapperProvider` with your object mapper in the `json-jackson` example in Jersey (see https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.x/examples/json-jackson) slightly modified

```
private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {

    ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
    result = result.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    result = result.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);
    result = result.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);

    result.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    result.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());

    return result;
}
```

it will work just fine.